# Jenkins pipeline not honoring agent specification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

At the pipeline level I specify the agent and node (with both the label and custom workspace).  When the pipeline kicks off it runs on the specified node, but when it hits the 'build job' picks the first available node.  I tried playing with the NodeLabel plugin, but that didn't work either.

This is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       node {
            label "Make Build Server"
            customWorkspace "$Workspace"
       }
    }
    options {
       skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
    stages {
        stage('PreBuild'){
            steps{
                input 'Did you authenticate the server through all the firewalls?'
            }
        }
        stage('Housekeeping'){
            steps{
                build job: 'Housekeeping'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `build` instruction in a Jenkinsfile, it's telling jenkins you want to build a completely separate job. It is *that other job* that will need to specify on what agent it will build. If it's a job based on a Jenkinsfile, then that other Jenkinsfile will indicate the agent. If it is a freestyle job, likewise. So the thing you were expecting--that the other job build on the agent you specified in the "parent Jenkinsfile"--is reasonable, but is not the way it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, a little confusing that it doesn't work specifically on building freestyle jobs out of the pipeline. Looking into other options now!