# Jenkins pipeline step happens on master instead of slave

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting started with Jenkins Pipeline. My pipeline has one simple step that is supposed to run on a different agent - like the "Restrict where this project can be run" option.

My problem is that it is running on master.

They are both Windows machines.

Here's my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent {label 'myLabel'}
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        echo pwd()
        writeFile(file: 'test.txt', text: 'Hello, World!')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`pwd()` prints `C:\Jenkins\workspace\<pipeline-name>_<branch-name>-Q762JIVOIJUFQ7LFSVKZOY5LVEW5D3TLHZX3UDJU5FWYJSNVGV4Q`.

This folder is on master. This is confirmed by the presence of the `test.txt` file.

I expected `test.txt` to be created on the slave agent.

#### Note 1

I can confirm that the pipeline finds the agent because the logs contain:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on MyAgent in C:\Jenkins\workspace\<pipeline-name>_<branch-name>-Q762JIVOIJUFQ7LFSVKZOY5LVEW5D3TLHZX3UDJU5FWYJSNVGV4Q
```

**But** this folder does not exist on MyAgent, which seems related to the problem.

#### Note 2

This question is similar to [Jenkins pipeline not honoring agent specification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46614297/3898322)
, except that I'm not using the `build` instruction so I don't think the answer applies.

### Note 3

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        echo "${env.NODE_NAME}"
      }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
      agent {label 'MyLabel'}
      steps {
          echo "${env.NODE_NAME}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This prints the expected output - `master` and `MyAgent`. If this is correct, then why is the workspace located in a different folder on master instead of being on MyAgent?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example

```
pipeline {
  agent none

    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            agent { label 'build-label' }
            steps {
                sh 'env'
                sh ' sleep 8'
            }
        }
        stage('Example Test') {
            agent { label 'deploy-label' }
            steps {
                sh 'env'
                sh ' sleep 5'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and the following pipeline code worked for me (i.e. the file got created on the Windows slave instead of Windows master),

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                node('myLabel'){
                    script {
                        writeFile(file: 'test.txt', text: 'Hello World!', encoding: 'UTF-8')
                    }
                    // This should print the file content on slave (Hello World!)
                    bat "type test.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm debugging a completely unrelated issue and this fact was thrown in my face. Apparently the pipeline is processed in the built-in node (previously known as the master node), with the steps being forwarded to the agent.

So even though `echo` runs on the agent, but `pwd()` will run on the built-in node. You can do `sh 'pwd'` to get the path on the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if it isn't a shell script or a batch file, the code will execute in a "flyweight" executor on the master.  This isn't a well known characteristic of Jenkins, and is the root of so much confusion.  How are you supposed to understand what is going on, if you don't even know where your code is executing.  It also begs the question of why even bother with using a scripting language that is so hog-tied that you can farm it out to nodes.  Might as well just make everything a shell script.

https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/pipeline-difference-between-flyweight-and-heavyweight-executors